# Using an object in a single class with multiple constructors

Tags: c#, class, oop, constructor, xna

This is the class that I build the constructors in, I want to have multiple "UserKeys" constructors, 1 for each character in my project but the main class doesn't recognize the second constructor only the first one (if I have a constructor that takes 0 arguments, it recognizes that and the first one, but not the second one)

```
abstract class BaseKeys
{
    public abstract bool LeftPressed();
    public abstract bool RightPressed();
    public abstract bool UpPressed();
    public abstract bool DownPressed();
    public abstract bool high_hitPressed();
    public abstract bool rope_jumpPressed();
    public abstract bool runRightPressed();
    public override bool leftRightPressed();
}

class UserKeys : BaseKeys
{
    #region data
    Keys left, right, up, down, walk;
    Keys combo, high_hit;
    #endregion

    #region ctor
    public UserKeys(Keys left, Keys right,
                    Keys up, Keys down, Keys high_hit)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.up = up;
        this.down = down;
        this.high_hit = high_hit;
    }

    public UserKeys(Keys right, Keys left, 
                    Keys down, Keys walk, Keys high_hit)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.down = down;
        this.high_hit = high_hit;
        this.walk = walk;
    }
}
```

Comment: What means "recognize", you get a compiler error? If so, tell it us. What is the code in the Main class that uses the constructor? Both constructors have the same parameters, that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by that: "i want to have multiple "UserKeys" Constructors, 1 for each character"?

Comment: i have few characters, batman subzero superman and flash.
i want to have constructor in UserKeys for each character that takes diffrent keys from the keyboad, for example i want to have an option of superman flying by clicking f, but flash doesnt need this fnuction, so i want to have few constructor options in the UserKeys class so i wont need to give for a character that i build keys from keyboard he doesnt use. and in my main class all i do is making new UserKeys object and i want to give it Keyboard Keys (example: up, down right, left, 'Z','X')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both constructors have the same parameters, that doesn't work. Only their names are different. You need to make them different:

```
public UserKeys(Keys left, Keys right,
                Keys up, Keys down, 
                Keys high_hit)
{
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.up = up;
    this.down = down;
    this.high_hit = high_hit;
}

public UserKeys(Keys left, Keys right, 
                Keys up, Keys down, 
                Keys high_hit, Keys walk)
{
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.up = up;
    this.down = down;
    this.high_hit = high_hit;
    this.walk = walk;
}
```

I've added `Keys up` to the second and used the same order as in the first(otherwise very confusing and error-prone). If you don't know `Keys up` pass `Keys.None`.